# Kahler intonation screws

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, bridge

I am looking to get some replacement intonation screws for the kahler bridge. Does anyone know what type of screw these as ordering from whammy parts would get expensive with shipping. I have placed the screw I'm looking for below, is there any alternatives?

https://www.whammyparts.com/kahler-replacement-parts/23xx-professional/kahler-clamp-plate-screw-detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact it states use a Phillips screwdriver, that head looks far more like a Pozidriv. You're probably not going to torque it so tight that it wrecks the screw or screwdriver bit, but it helps to use the right tool!

Need to take a sample along to an ironmongers - or machine shop, where the *thread* can be established. If it's made in the States, it could well be an imperial thread, otherwise it's going to be a metric. They all come in different pitches for the same diameter, but a thread gauge will verify which. Then it's simply a matter of buying a packet of them - maybe £1 for ten! If they're too long, it's a simple matter to saw them to length. Good luck!